# Single Asp:button for two action in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am need to use on button for two action. Is it Possible?

One is normal user click event and another is java script use  click-event when it condition satisfied. Is it any way to do like that?

```
 C#
 <asp:Button ID="btnCrop" runat="server" Text="Crop"    OnClick="btnCrop_Click"  Width="41px"  />   


 JS:

 document.getElementById('<%=btnCrop.ClientID%>').click();
```

here JS achieved one action. I want to achieve, when user click the button that uses different method name.

Comment: Why not just add an addition functionality in that click event? For example if you want to runa Javascript why not just call the Javascript in the click event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have to handle `OnClientClick` event.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" 
             runat="server" 
             Text="Button"
             OnClientClick="return doSomething()"
             OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<script>
  function doSomething() {
    return confirm("Do something");
  }
</script>
```